# red5 1.0.1 : truncated recorded stream .flv.ser : Error -18 truncated box

Tags: stream, record, red5, truncated

I've recorded streams using **streamPublishStart** callback with Red5 streaming server. It works. But a few times, the internet connection **fall down** in the publisher side. Then, in the streams directory, I have got a *.flv.ser file*. It's not playable. I've tried to repair/fix it with all software that propose it. No success. I've use **flvcheck.exe** and the report is :  **Error -18 truncated box**. I've seen discussion on Adobe forums but no interesting things. Could you propose me a technic or a software to solve my problem.

thanks in advance,

Pascal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm late to the party but you simply have to concatenate the files. On Linux this works like this:

```
cat foo.flv foo.flv.ser > playable_foo.flv
```

I read that somewhere else but I forgot where it was.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get your question answered? The .flv.ser is a temp file, created until Red5 is done processing the stream.  When done, there is a new file without the .ser extension.  What I had to do was create a ajax script that looks at the directory for a .flv.ser file and prevents closing the page until the conversion is completed.  Red5 version one is slow at doing the conversion.  I'm testing 1.0.2 RC1 right now, but initial results look like it is even worse.  I hear version .8 is the best for recording so I may have to downgrade to that.